# No finite projective resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R=k[x^2 ,x^3]$ be the subring of $A=k[x]$ generated by $x^2$ and $x^3$ .Let $I=(x^2,x^3)$ .

$(i)$ Show that neither $A$ nor $R/I$ admit finite projective resolution as $R$-modules.

$(ii)$ Compute $Tor_n^R( A , R/I)$ and $Tor_n^R(R/I,R/I)$.

$(iii)$ Show that $A\otimes_R A$ is isomorphic to $A \times A/(x^2)$.

For $(i)$ the given hint is Construct a resolution $....\rightarrow R^2 \rightarrow R^2 \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$ .

I am unable to construct such a resolution. For $(ii)$  I am able to compute that $Tor_1^R( R/I , R/I)$ is isomorphic to $I/I^2$ . But I am unable to solve the problem. Need some help . Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you asking us to solve some homework: see [Exercise 7](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~temkin/teach/math599/HW6.pdf).

Comment: This homework was not assigned to me.I got that homework paper from internet and was trying to solve this problem but  got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the resolution. The map $R\to R/I$
is the projection with kernel $I=(x^2,x^3)$. Try for the next map
$d_1:R^2\to R$ with $d_1(f,g)=x^2f+x^3g$. Its image is obviously $I$.
What about its kernel $K_1$? Then $K_1=\{(f,g):x^2 f+x^3 g=0\}$.
Let $f=a_0+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$ and
$g=b_0+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots$. For $(f,g)$ to lie in the kernel $K$,
we need $a_0=0$, $b_0=0$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=-b_2$, $a_4=-b_3$ etc. Thus
$f=x^3 h(x)$ and $g=-x^2h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial in $k[x]=A$.
So $K$ is isomorphic to $A$ (and to $I$) as an $R$-module.
Now define $d_2:R^2\to R^2$ by $d_2(u,v)=(x^2 u+x^3v,-x^3 u-x^4v)$.
Its image is $K_1$. What is its kernel $K_2$? Well it's the same as $K_1$. Therefore we can take all higher differentials in the complex
to equal $d_2$ and the complex never terminates. We also get a resolution
of $A$ for free.

For $\mathrm{Tor}_1^{R/I}(R/I,R/I)\cong I/I^2$ note that $I^2$
is spanned by monomials $x^4,x^5,x^6,\ldots$ so $I/I^2$ has dimension
$2$ over $R/I\cong k$, and is generated by the images of $x$ and $x^2$.